# How to prove $\mathrm{supp} ~ R(t)\in \{|x|<t\}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $R(t)$ define as $$R(t):=F^{-1} \left(\frac{\sin |\xi|t}{|\xi|} \right),$$ how to show that 
$$\mathrm{supp} ~ R(t)\in \{|x|<t\},$$
where $F$ is the Fourier transform.

Comment: Did you mean to include $t$ in the function you are Fourier transforming? If so, what is the transform variable?

Comment: Do you know what the Fourier transform of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is?

Comment: @DanielFischer: I don't know, advanced details please!

Comment: (-1), I can't see any kind of effort here...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Let $f(x)=0$ when $x\notin(0,1)$ and  $f(x)=1$ for $x\in(0,1)$.

What is the Fourier transform of $f$?

---

Adding some details.
$$\hat{f}(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-itx}dx=\int_{0}^1 e^{-itx}dx=\frac{e^{-itx}-1}{-it}$$
Do you see how to continue?

Comment: Could you provide the more details for me? Because I'm not familiar with the Fourier Analysis. :)

Comment: Do you really answer my question, I can't follow you? Could post the complete solution or some reference?

Comment: @A.Hoo In this case $f$ is the inverse Fourier transform of $\hat{f}$ and the support is $(0,1)$. This is a hint, you should look closer at it and realize how to reach your $\hat{f}$; that is you should look closer to $f(x)=1$ on $(-1,1)$ and continue to work from there. Regarding references, you should add your references - e.g. *why* are you looking at this if you are not that familiar with Fourier analysis?

Comment: Also, this is *one* of several normalizations of the Fourier transform.

Comment: @ AD : Please let me think about it. Thank your hint! :)